# Cant pull data for select query, except between dates

Tags: select

I thought I have all the codes correct to pull a report by between dates and by group.id. But the filter message No Order Found. How to get the filter_class.php select where by group.id = index_class.php dropdown selected numeric value. I've been searching and trying everything I've learned no success.
Any help would be appreciated. If I put the group.id number in the filter_class.php select where by group.id = 4 manually, it will pull the report by that number. But it needs to pull the report based on the dropdown list on index_class.php.

I can pull the report just fine with the datepicker between dates, but I need it to pull by date and group.id number.

codes below

```
index_class.php

       <div class="col-md-3">
       <input type="text" name="from_date" id="from_date" class="form-control" placeholder="From Date" />
       </div>

       <div class="col-md-3">
       <input type="text" name="to_date" id="to_date" class="form-control" placeholder="To Date" />
       </div>

        <div class="col-md-3"> 
       <input type="button" name="filter" id="filter" value="Filter" class=".btn-mini btn-info" /> 
         </div>

Drop down pulls data from database
------------------------------------

    <div class="col-md-4"> 
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
    //////////////////////
    $.getJSON("classes-data.php", function(return_data){
        $.each(return_data.data, function(key,value){
        $("#class").append("<option value=" + value.id +">"+value.name+"</option>");    

        });
    });
    //////////////////////
    ////////////

    $('#class').change(function(){
    //var st=$('#class option:selected').text();
    var st=$('#class').val();
    //alert(st);
    });
    /////////////////////
    });

    </script>
    <select id=class id=class>
    </select>
    </div>

Datepicker code
----------------
 <script>  
      $(document).ready(function(){  
           $.datepicker.setDefaults({  
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'   
           });  
           $(function(){  
                $("#from_date").datepicker();  
                $("#to_date").datepicker();  
           });  
           $('#filter').click(function(){
                var from_date = $('#from_date').val();  
                var to_date = $('#to_date').val();
                if(from_date != '' && to_date != '')
                {  
                     $.ajax({  
                          url:"filter_class.php",
                          method:"POST",  
                          data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},  
                          success:function(data)  
                          {  
                               $('#order_table').html(data);  
                          }  
                     });  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                     alert("Please Select Date");  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 </script>

   filter_class.php

   -------------------

     $query = "
                    SELECT * FROM attendance_record, _person,  _person_group
                   WHERE _person.id = attendance_record.personid AND _person_group.id = $('#class').val()
    and date BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND '".$_POST["to_date"]."' 
    ORDER BY _person_group.id ASC

                     ";

            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```